# Big O confusion

Tags: big-o

I'm testing out some functions I made and I am trying to figure out the time complexity.
My problem is that even after reading up on some articles on Big O I can't figure out what the following should be:

> 1000 loops : 15000 objects : time 6
>
> 1000 loops : 30000 objects : time 9
>
> 1000 loops : 60000 objects : time 15
>
> 1000 loops : 120000 objects : time 75

The difference between the first 2 is 3 ms, then 6 ms, and then 60, so the time doubles up with each iteration. I know this isn't O(n), and I think it's not O(log n).

When I try out different sets of data, the time doesn't always go up. For example take this sequence (ms): 11-17-26-90-78-173-300

The 78 ms looks out of place. Is this even possible?

Edit:
**NVM, I'll just have to talk this over with my college tutor.
The output of time differs too much with different variables.
Thanks for those who tried to help though!**

Comment: Big O has only an asymptotic meaning. It is not related to measures. It is a way to say something about theoretical behavior, for increasing large input, of a program or algorithm.

Comment: In other words, it answers the question -- "how well does this scale?"

Comment: I know what Big O is.
I just can't figure out the Big O complexity of this data output.

Comment: You don't get Big O from data output.  You get it from the algorithm.

Comment: The data output in this case is time in ms for the function to complete. From this I should be able to conclude the Big O right?

The algorithm is executed within this function. How else would you do it?

Comment: @user1114664: Stop trying to compute the Big O from just running time data. It's not how it works. Can't you show us the computation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big O notation is not about how long it takes exactly for an operation to complete. It is a (very rough) estimation of how various algorithms compare asymptotically with respect to changing input sizes, expressed in generic "steps". That is "how many steps does my algorithm do for an input of N elements?".

Having said this, note that in the Big O notation constants are ignored. Therefore a loop over N elements doing 100 calculations at each iteration would be 100 * N but still equal to O(N). Similarly, a loop doing 10000 calculations would still be O(N).

Hence in your example, if you have something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      // computations
```

it would be 1000 * N = O(N).

Big O is just a simplified algorithm running time estimation, which basically says that if an algorithm has running time O(N) and another one has O(N^2) then the first one will *eventually* be faster than the second one for some value of N. This estimation of course does not take into account anything related to the underlying platform like CPU speed, caching, I/O bottlenecks, etc.

Comment: ...I appreciate the answer, but I'm not looking for the definition of Big O.

I just can't figure out the Big O order for my set of time data.

Comment: @user1114664: Please show us the computation. There is no way to know the Big O without analyzing the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't get *O(n)* from theory alone, then I think you need to look over more orders of magnitude in *O(n)* -- at least three, preferably six or more (you will just need to experiment to see what variation in *n* is required).  Leave the thing running overnight if you have to.  Then plot the results logarithmically.

Basically I suspect you are looking at noise right now.

Comment: It's a really simple function though. Running it overnight would be overkill for such a college assignment.

And how would I plot such data ? Im using Java, do you know any tools?

Comment: The easiest way to plot this is with graph paper, or with a ruler.  Or you can use a spreadsheet and just copy your results in there -- you only need 5-6 data points.  And since you can do 1000 iterations in milliseconds, I expect you  can get plenty of orders of magnitude in under an hour.  (BTW: I suspect your funcation is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your actual algorithm, I can only guess:
If you allow a constant initialisation overhead of 3ms, you end up with

```
1000x15,000 = (OH:3) + 3
1000x30,000 = (OH:3) + 6
1000x60,000 = (OH:3) + 12
```

This, to me, appears to be O(n)

The disparity in your timestamping of differing datasets could be due to any number of factors.

Comment: Meh...
When i try it with 120,000 objects it outputs:
75 ms...
This can't be O(n)...

I really can't figure this one out...

Comment: Without seeing your algorithm, I really can't speculate further. You're trying to timestamp a process on a pre-empting cpu. values are erroneous at best.